# Ways To Restrict Connected App Access?

Tags: api, connected-apps

I am exploring around different ways to block users from installing/using connected app, unless they have necessary permissions like `Modify All` , `Manage Connected Apps` etc.

I have enabled `API Access Control` , I wanted to understand if anyone here has any idea how to restrict users access to install/access third party apps other than `API Access Control`? and is there a way to show a generic message or error page displaying custom message say e.g I have blocked `Workbench` and if user tries to use/install `workbench` I want to display custom error message like  `You don't have permission to install/use this App, Please reach out to abc@mycompany.com` .

[image]